# Google Oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch when send request from localhost

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I use Google OAuth2 for my codeigniter application and i send request using the HybridIgniter.

REDIRECT URIS : http://localhost/college-rating-system/hauth/endpoint.

JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS : http://localhost

When send request from localhost then we get 400 error that is,

Error : redirect_uri_mismatch

Any idea ..?

Comment: check the full error. It will tell you the URL its coming from.  The redirect URI must match exactly.

Comment: that send error that is:

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/college-rating-system/index.php/hauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Google did not match a registered redirect URI.

Comment: exactly as I said it needs to match exactly what you have placed in the Google developer console.

Comment: thanks DaImTo,  error solve by puting that url

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the full error it will tell you the URL its coming from.

The redirect URI must match exactly what you have placed in the Google developer console.

Answer (score 4):

Redirect URIs

http://localhost:8000/      this **/** at end solve my problem
JavaScript origins

http://localhost:8000

**NOTE: localhost and 127.0.0.1 conflicts can create problems for you sometime**

Comment: changing authorized redirect from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" solved it for me (2020)

Comment: trailing slash was the issue for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a mention of `OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT` env var [tucked away in these docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#example).

```
  # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification.
  # ACTION ITEM for developers:
  #     When running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
```